# Mobius Funcions of the posets

Tags: combinatorics

For a poset, where $n = 2$ we have that two comparable points $1<2$ so $R = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}). \ $ For two incomparable points $R=\{(1,1),(2,2)\} \ $. Now, for $n=4$ we have $1<3, 2<3,2<4. \ $ For the pentagon $n=5$, $1<2<5,1<3<4<5, \ $ so our Hasse diagram will look like:

[image]

But I am not sure how to calculate the Mobius Functions of these posets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work directly from the recursive formula for $\mu(x,y)$:

$$\mu(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x=y\\
-\sum\limits_{x\le z<y}\mu(x,z),&\text{if }x<y\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

I’ll calculate $\mu(1,y)$ for $y=1,2,3,4,5$ for the last poset as an illustration.

- First, $\mu(1,1)=1$ by definition.
- $1<2$, so $\mu(1,2)=-\sum\limits_{1\le z<2}\mu(1,z)=-\mu(1,1)=-1$.
- Essentially the same calculation applies to $3$ and $4$, so $\mu(1,3)=\mu(1,4)=-1$.
- Finally, $\mu(1,5)=-\sum_{1\le z<5}\mu(1,z)=-\sum_{k=1}^4\mu(1,k)=-(1-1-1-1)=2$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Luffy: You're welcome!

Comment: Brian, how did you get the summation of 4 on $\sum^4_{k=1}\mu(1,k)$?

Comment: @Luffy: I’m not sure what you’re asking: the sum is $-2$, so the negative of the sum is $2$. The indiovidual terms, $\mu(1,1)$ through $\mu(1,4)$,  were all calculated above that.

Comment: I am confused on how you calculated your summation. I understand how you got $1<2$ but not $1<3,1<4,1<5$ i.e. $\mu(1,3), \mu(1,4),\mu(1,5)$.

Comment: @Luffy: The calculations for $\mu(1,3)$ and $\mu(1,4)$ are virtually identical to the calculation for $\mu(1,2)$, since $3$ and $4$ are related to $1$ in exactly the same way that $2$ is.